# Pass query string to same method in controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am Trying To Reload Contents Of Page. Through link button Filter In PHP
By Passing Some Value Through Query String To Controller Method.
The Controller Method Loads The Same Page From Where I am Passing Query String.
But The View Is Not Reloading.
But If I Call The Controller Method Some Other View It Works Fine.
here is my code

mainview.php

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>maincontroller?language=English">English</a>
```

maincontroller.php

Here Is The Index Method Of Controller.

```
    $movielanguage=$this->input->get('language');
    if(!empty($movielanguage))
        {
            $moviedata['popularmovies']=$this->main_model- 
            >getmoviebylanguage($movielanguage);
        }

    $moviedata['allmovies']=$this->main_model->getAllMovies();
    $this->load->view('home/mainview.php',$moviedata);
}
```

Here View Does Not Refresh Its Contents
How Can I Solve This

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

***First*** if you want a single view ,should put you code it in `if else` condition and second assign your data in same variable

Your code should be like this :

```
public function index()
{
    $movielanguage=$this->input->get('language');
    if(! empty($movielanguage))
    {
        $moviedata['movies']=$this->main_model->getmoviebylanguage($movielanguage);
    }
    else
    {
        $moviedata['movies']=$this->main_model->getAllMovies();
    }

    $this->load->view('home/mainview.php',$moviedata);
}
```

**Second** : and if you want to add different view for different category of movies

You can do like this :

```
public function index()
{
    $movielanguage=$this->input->get('language');
    if(! empty($movielanguage))
    {
        $moviedata['popularmovies']=$this->main_model->getmoviebylanguage($movielanguage);
        /*popularview is just an example*/
        $this->load->view('home/popularview.php',$moviedata);

    }
    else
    {
        $moviedata['allmovies']=$this->main_model->getAllMovies();
        /*allview is just an example*/
        $this->load->view('home/allview.php',$moviedata);
    }
}
```